# C# open outlook mail window

Tags: c#, email, outlook, office-interop, com-interop

I have a simple application written in C # .net 6.0. After pressing the button, I would like to open an Outlook window with the content of the e-mail from the textbox and the recipient from the textbox.

The problem is that the application is used on computers in the corporate domain. I cannot send emails programmatically using smtp.

Mail must be banned exactly from the account of the person who is currently logged on to the computer (window 10), who has his Outlook account configured so that it is assigned to a windows account.

I tried to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook but I get an error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, Version = 15.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 71e9bce111e9429c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook but I get an error

You need to add a COM reference to the project. Right click on the dependencies of your project and choose `Add COM references`:

[image: COM references VS2022]

In the dialog window you can find the entry for Outlook and select it.

[image: Outlook COM reference]

Viola! Click the `Ok` button and use the OOM in your code.

Comment: I do what You show me and it's work super. Now I must only make to open Outlook main window. Because if outlook is closed, email is not sended - go to draft. If outlook is opened - it's work super. Thank You again.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook/). This will resolve your error and provide a programmable way to interact with Outlook.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
```

Comment: It is absolutely not necessarily to use third-party assemblies from NuGet.

Comment: I add nuget package :)

Comment: There is no need to add a nuget package if you add a COM reference to the project. Moreover, one of the goals of nuget packages is an ability to get updates and upgrades of dependencies. In case of interop assemblies it doesn't make any sense.